# how to calculate g-force for a cnc machine passing a 90 degree corner with a certain speed.

Tags: geometry

For a cnc machine, robot I need to know the gforce value when machine is passing
trough corners.

The goal is to use a maximum gforce value for a machine, that will be respected by the path  planner, then machine can travel trough a corner with acceptable velocity cq. gforce.

Foreword : I started using arc's to calculate g-force using
a formula for the acceleration of a centrifuge is: $a = 4 \pi^2 r n^2$.

1. I could convert the velocity [mm/s] into revolutions a second [rps] for a 3 point arc :
   $$
   \begin{align}
       \text{circumference}={M_{PI}}\cdot(2\cdot\text{radius})\\
       \text{rps}=\text{speed}_\mathrm{mm/sec}/\text{circumference}
   \end{align}
   $$
2. Calculate the g-force a [mm/s2]
   $$
   a=4\cdot M_{PI}^2\cdot\text{radius}\cdot \text{rps}^2
   $$
3. Conversion from [mm/s2] to [g].
   $$
   a=0.0001
   $$
   Question : is the above approach mathematical correct when running along an arc path?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.